# How can i customize a checkout page from WP travel plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I have a checkout page in my wordpress website that comes with WP travel plugin . the page is implemented using a shortcode `[wp_travel_checkout]`.
I am trying to customize the checkout page so I add another payment button (google pay), but I dont know how to access the page while only having the shortcode.
is it possible to edit shortcode pages in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new file in your theme folder called page-checkout.php (checkout is a slug of your page, if your page is located at example.com/travelcheckout/ then the file must be named page-travelcheckout.php)
Then copy the content of page.php into this file

Find here in the code the_content() function, and after it you can add your code for a new button